# How to check if node have childNode before removing it?

Tags: javascript, nodes, removechild

## I just got this weird error:

[image]

And I don't know how that happened.
`.contains()` should return `true` only if `placeholder` is a child of `overParent`, but how can that return true and dont have `placeholder` as it's child?

## Solutions I need:

1. Why and How this error is happening?
2. A better solution to remove `placheholder` only when it's a child of `overParent`.

## Observations:

I'm doing this on react.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is, although `.contains` tells you that `placeholder` is a descendant of `overParent`, it can be a *grandchild* node. If that's the case, you are trying to remove a node which is in another node from `overParent`.

For demonstration purposes, check if the actual DOM looks like this:

```
- overParent
    - <some node>
       - placeholder
```

To avoid errors like this, go to the direct parent of the node you want to remove and call `removeChild` on it instead:

```
if (overParent.contains(placeholder)) {
    placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: If you want to only remove the placeholder if it is the child of parent, you can use

`if (placeholder.parentNode === overParent) {
    overParent.removeChild(placeholder);
}`